# Rotate X, Y and Z axis all together

Tags: objective-c, swift, catransform3d

[image]

I first 3D rotate a flat figure in Illustrator or Photoshop, get the exact angles(x, y and z) applied to it in the design tool and then apply the same angles to a UILabel placed on top of the image to synchronize them visually.

I've figured out how to rotate 2 axis at the same time by using CATransform3DConcat but then I'm not sure how to apply the third.

```
float angleX = -18 * M_PI / 180;
CATransform3D t1 = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angleX, 1, 0, 0);
float angleY = -26 * M_PI / 180;
CATransform3D t2 = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angleY, 0, 1, 0);
CATransform3D combo1 = CATransform3DConcat(t1, t2);
self.labelPlay.layer.transform = combo1;
```

**EDIT**

Trying this now but still no good.
Tried all combinations of different orders but nothing.

```
float angleX = -18 * M_PI / 180;
CATransform3D t1 = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angleX, 1, 0, 0);
float angleY = -26 * M_PI / 180;
CATransform3D t2 = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angleY, 0, 1, 0);
float angleZ = 8 * M_PI / 180;
CATransform3D t3 = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angleZ, 0, 0, 1);

self.label.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DConcat(t3, t2), t1);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can rotate in any direction by specifying different values for the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th arguments to CATransform3DMakeRotation.

Comment: I first 3D rotate a flat square in Illustrator or Photoshop, get the exact angles(x, y and z) applied to it in the design tool and then apply the same angles to a UILabel placed on top of the square to synchronize them visually.

Comment: The order will matter. Can you show exactly what you want it to do, and what it's currently doing instead?

Comment: Just uploaded an image. The push button on the left is the one I'm trying to achieve but right now with the above code, it gives me the one on the right. I also have to apply z axis but haven't figured out how to add a third angle either.

Comment: Have you tried adding another `CATransform3DMakeRotation`?

Comment: I have but it doesn't change a thing. I'm probably doing the entire thing completely wrong because it shouldn't rotate it like that when only applied x and y either. So there's something wrong with the posted code plus z axis that I haven't applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure but I think this might be it.

For designers thinking angles from 3D rotation in Illustrator/Photoshop would just work with CATransform3D, it's almost true but you might have to change one tiny thing.

Let's say you have x : -18, y : -26 and z : 8 in your design tool. Switching y and z to positive/negative solved my problem. So now I have -

```
float angleX = -18 * M_PI / 180;
CATransform3D t1 = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angleX, 1, 0, 0);
float angleY = 26 * M_PI / 180;
CATransform3D t2 = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angleY, 0, 1, 0);
float angleZ = -8 * M_PI / 180;
CATransform3D t3 = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angleZ, 0, 0, 1);

self.label.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DConcat(t1, t2), t3);
```

I can't tell you why exactly but this rotates properly.

Comment: I was coming to this conclusion as well. If you look at the little glyph next to the -26° field, it shows a rotation that should move the cube's face to the right. The angle you chose is negative, yet the face does go to the right. So it's really opposite of what it should be, I think.

Comment: That's true.. I haven't noticed those until just now. But then again if you look at the one for Z axis, even though it insinuates the angle should be positive and it appears to be positive, turning it negative actually rotated properly so it's confusing. Anyway it's solved yay!